# Facing cross domain issue when using lightsteamer(for streaming)

Tags: javascript, streaming, lightstreamer

My web server is running on localhost:8080 and my lightstreamer server is running on localhost:8989. But when I try to connect to lightstreamer, I am facing cross domain problem. I know that, this could be solved by having my web app in lightstream server. But is there any better solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version in use

On older version the [setDomain](http://www.lightstreamer.com/docs/client_html_jsdoc/index.html) method needs to be used.

On the latest version, by default, you should not have such issue. 
Anyway you may want to check http://goo.gl/kwREX to see how the server have to be configured depending on your deploy environment; by default is configured as accept-all.

[Disclaimer I work @ weswit, weswit makes Lightstreamer]